# When to use DhcpOptions

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I recently started working with AWS CloudFormation and encountered the resource DhcpOptions. 
Can anyone tell me, when I would need to include this resource in my template?

Thank you.

Comment: see [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ko_kr/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_DHCP_Options.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use of the resource `AWS::EC2::DHCPOptions` [1] is optional.
AWS by default creates this resource for you and associates it to your VPC using a `AWS::EC2::VPCDHCPOptionsAssociation` resource.

The setting is used to configure the (AWS-provided) DHCP-Server in your VPC. The attributes you assign to the resource are translated into *DHCP Options* which are passed to any of your EC2 instances once they request the information via DHCP protocol, e.g.
CloudFormation `DomainName` is translated into `Domain Name Server Option` (see Section 3.8 in RFC 2132 [3]). For an overview of all exisiting BOOTP and DHCP options, see the IETF document on the website of IANA [4] or the respective wikipedia article [5].

AWS defines the DHCP Option Set in their docs [5] as:

> The Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol (DHCP) provides a standard for passing configuration information to hosts on a TCP/IP network. The options field of a DHCP message contains the configuration parameters. Some of those parameters are the domain name, domain name server, and the netbios-node-type.
>
> You can configure DHCP options sets for your virtual private clouds (VPC).

#### When to use the DHCPOptions resource?

As far as I know, the DHCP options of a VPC are often modified in order to change the network's default DNS server. If you have your clients configured to obtain the DNS servers via DHCP (which is standard for Amazon Linux and Amazon Linux 2), you can change their DNS servers by creating a new DHCP options set and setting a custom *domain-name-servers* option.

That is of course only on aspect of network configuration. By changing other options, such as the `ntp-servers` option, you can modify other configuration values which are sent over your VPC network when requested by DHCP clients (such as EC2 instances).

Note: Once you create a `AWS::EC2::DHCPOptions` resource, do not forget to assign it to a VPC using the `AWS::EC2::VPCDHCPOptionsAssociation` resource.

#### What is the default DHCP option set?

The docs [6] state:

> When you create a VPC, we automatically create a set of DHCP options and associate them with the VPC. This set includes two options: domain-name-servers=AmazonProvidedDNS, and domain-name=domain-name-for-your-region.

That is for the domain-name-servers option:

> AmazonProvidedDNS is an Amazon DNS server, and this option enables DNS for instances that need to communicate over the VPC's Internet gateway. The string AmazonProvidedDNS maps to a DNS server running on a reserved IP address at the base of the VPC IPv4 network range, plus two. For example, the DNS Server on a 10.0.0.0/16 network is located at 10.0.0.2.

#### References

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ec2-dhcp-options.html
[2] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ec2-vpc-dhcp-options-assoc.html
[3] https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2132
[4] https://www.iana.org/assignments/bootp-dhcp-parameters/bootp-dhcp-parameters.xhtml
[5] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol#Options
[6] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_DHCP_Options.html

Comment: Thank you. Would you personally leave the DHCP settings as default?

Comment: Personally, I never had a requirement to change that setting. In particular AmazonProvidedDNS was always desirable for me since I use Route53's private hosted zones.